# Problem in formulating question

Tags: questions, speech

Consider this scenario..*.Sam ate 4 cookies*. Now if someone asks Sam *How many you had*, then Sam will reply 4. But how should the question be formed so that the answer Sam gives will be 4th instead of 4?

Answer (score 0):

`Ordinal number` means the order of a number in a sequence (e.g. first, second, third etc).

So the question could be phrased as-: What is the `ordinal number` of the last cookie Sam ate?

Comment: Thanks @suspectus but if the scenario we are facing or the situation is a totally informal one, won't the answer u suggested sound a bit too technical or formal..?

Comment: @user308123 there are already two questions (listed above) with numerous answers, maybe some of those answers will help.